# How to add add data at the top of a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, data-structures

I am developing an android calendar app that displays dates in a listview. I was able to implement the addition of data to the listview while scrolling down. Now I want to do the same while scrolling up. How can I add data to the top of the listview and also scroll beyond the first data of the listview?

Here is my code.

```
public class AllEventFragment extends Fragment{
private final int INITIAL_DAYS = 14;

private final int THRESHOLD = 14;
private  int currentPage = 0;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLastItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,   
        int totalItemCount) {

            if (loading){
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal){
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    currentPage++;
                }
                if(totalItemCount < totalItemCount){
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    currentPage++;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + THRESHOLD)){
                addMoreDaysToBottom( currentPage + 1);
                loading = true;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Vector to store the items.

Implement ListAdapter which returns the items inside that Vector.

When you need to add an item at the top, insert it as the first element of that Vector

Refresh the adapter of the ListView

Comment: i have done that and have been able to add data while scrolling down (but didn't add that part of the code to the snippet shown above). My issue now is how to programmatically add data to the top of the list when a user tries go beyond the first element in the ArrayList. in other words an inverse of what i have already done.

Comment: do you mean like pull-to-refresh effect of Facebook app?

Comment: not really pulling to refresh effect actually. A close example is the "Load Earlier Messages" in WhatsApp chat listView. Since mine is a calendar app, the dates of previous days will be added to the listView when a user tries to go beyond the first initialized element in the arraylist (i.e today's date). How do i determine when a user tries to go beyond the first elememt of the arraylist through ScrollListener.

Comment: View c = listview.getChildAt(0);
int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
if scrolly is zero, it means the list is at the top. But if you want a overscroll effect, you need some more work